# How to get variable from a class initially declared in a super class?

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes, each of them in different files. 
I tried to access the variable `$this->_myvalue` initially defined in the **Class Second** from **Class First** but not success with the error message **Using $this when not in object context**
Can someone please tell how am I not able to get the `$this->_value` from Class Second?

```
//File First.php
Class First extends Second{

     function some_function(){
         new Second($this->_myvalue); //Using $this when not in object context
     }
}

//File Second.php
Class Second extends Third{
     public $myvalue;
     public function __construct($myvalue = null) {
        $this->_myvalue = $myvalue;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating a new instance of Second inside a class that extends Second? This suggests a lack of understanding of OOP inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're misunderstanding inheritance:

```
class Parent
{
    public $val;

    public function __construct($val = null) {
        $this->val = $val;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public function something() {
        echo $this->val;
    }
}
```

You can now do

```
$parent = new Parent(5);
echo $parent->val; // 5

$child = new Child(10); // __construct is inherited from Parent
echo $child->val; // 10 - public $val is also inherited
$child->something(); // 10
```